# Download an array of documents from firestore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can i fetch certain an **array of documents** from **firestore**?

I have users and each users have certain **id**. This **id** has the same name as document in **firestore**. For example:

**First user** have **id** in branch:

- City
- Oko

**Second user** have **id** in branch:

- 001Zaria0029
- Avangard

My users stored in **database** like this:

[image]

In **firestore** this data **stored** like this:

[image]

So when **first user** enters the app, he must see `City` and `Oko` or when **second user** enters the app, he must see `001Zaria0029` and `Avangard`.

How do I get different data for users? Without changing the structure in **firestore**.

I think need add id's in array and fetch from firestore, but I can't figure out how to request such an array. Pls help.

I know how to collect an id’s into an array, but then I cannot understand how to request this array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "array fetch" in Firestore.  If you need multiple documents, simply request them each individually using multiple calls to [getDocument()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference#getdocumentcompletion).

Comment: I thought about it, but thought there was a way to make is easier

Comment: There are batch updates, if that what you're thinking of.  No batch fetches.